# Print a spreadsheet with no collating, two copies, landscape

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I tried doing a macro and that did not work.  I cannot get my code to uncollate when printing. It needs to print 1,1,1 then 2,2,2,2 etc etc.  I have tried collate:=true collate:=false nothing works.  Does it have to do with printer settings?  I want to create a macro on the excel page and the user just selects the macro and it just prints them out how I need.
Any ideas?

```
Sub UNCOLLATEDPRINT()
'
' UNCOLLATEDPRINT Macro
'
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut copies:=2, Collate:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN [link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838253.aspx) suggests that the default using `.PrintOut` is `False` for `Collate`.  Therefore, you will likely need to disable collate as a default option on your printer settings (varies by model).